# what data structure should be used in neo4j database to store combinations of elements

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I've combinations of data to save in database. For eg: A+B+C is one combination. B+C+D is other. 
Conditions:
1. A+B+C is same as B+A+C, C+B+A etc.
2. Also, each node will have an attribute called "weight". This depends on combination(In A+B+C combination, A 5g, B 6g and C 7g. Please note the third node will also have weight. Hence "weight" cannot be relationship).

Issues:
First: I have decided to go with graph database. But don't know how to meet the above conditions. If I go with undirected graph, A-B-C is a combination. But it can't return B-A-C as other. Since there is no connection from A to C.

Second: "weight" can't be a property in node, Because weight differs as per the combination. Also it can't be a relationship. Since the last node will also have weight to be considered.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I didn't know this. Sorry for that. Can I change the question as "Can Neo4j handle this? or  How to handle this in Neo4j?". I have no idea to go ahead with this.

Comment: You might read [the guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: where else can I ask a question like this? Please help.

Comment: @User1230321 I think that the question can be restated as follows: what data structure should be used in the neo4j database to store unsorted combinations of elements.

Comment: @stdob--, thanks for your suggestion. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Each combination can have a `Combination` node with `WEIGHT` relationships to the nodes in that combination.